# Always-on-top Layout with ScrollView

Tags: android, android-scrollview

So what I'm going to do is make a custom `MediaPlayer` Layout within my app.
The result should be like this

[image: HERE]

As you can see in the picture, the bottom MediaPlayer controller panel is ALWAYS on top of the ScrollView in the middle.
You can Scroll the stuff in the middle but you can also click on the button at t he bottom.
So what can I do to make this happen?

my own MediaPlayer control panel

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Stop1"
        style="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.Button.Small"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="◼" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Play1"
        style="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.Button.Small"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="▶" />

    <SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/Seekbar1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

scroll content

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView4"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Some text here as title"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/Handrail_ER"
                style="@android:style/Widget.Button.Small"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="ButtonName 1" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/Handrail_WR"
                style="@android:style/Widget.Button.Small"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="ButtonName 2" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/Handrail_AUS"
                style="@android:style/Widget.Button.Small"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="ButtonName 3" />
        </LinearLayout>


    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Edit:
This is my goal
[GOAL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2fQrb.png)

Edit 2:
Source code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="to.epac.factorycraft.drawerlayouttest.KCRstationActivity">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="九廣東鐵廣播"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/AdultTickets"
                        style="@android:style/Widget.Button.Small"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="成人車票" />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/BczOfTheRain"
                        style="@android:style/Widget.Button.Small"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="天雨關係" />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/CrossTrack"
                        style="@android:style/Widget.Button.Small"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="橫過路軌" />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/LifeAnimals"
                        style="@android:style/Widget.Button.Small"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="本公司" />

                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/ER_NoSmoke"
                        style="@android:style/Widget.Button.Small"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="請勿吸煙" />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/ER_PickPocket"
                        style="@android:style/Widget.Button.Small"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="提防扒手" />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/ER_Slippers"
                        style="@android:style/Widget.Button.Small"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="拖鞋涼鞋" />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/ER_SvcEnd"
                        style="@android:style/Widget.Button.Small"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="車站關閉" />

                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/ER_WetFloor_1"
                        style="@android:style/Widget.Button.Small"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="小心濕滑地面" />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/ER_WetFloor_2"
                        style="@android:style/Widget.Button.Small"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="上落車濕滑地面" />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/Esclator"
                        style="@android:style/Widget.Button.Small"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="當使用電梯時" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/Esclator_2"
                        style="@android:style/Widget.Button.Small"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="上落樓梯緊扶手" />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/Luggage_1"
                        style="@android:style/Widget.Button.Small"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="大型行李 升降機" />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/TakeCareChild"
                        style="@android:style/Widget.Button.Small"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="照顧同行小童" />

                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/Luggage_2"
                        style="@android:style/Widget.Button.Small"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="笨重行李 升降機" />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/MetallicBalloon"
                        style="@android:style/Widget.Button.Small"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="金屬氣球" />

                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/WetFloor"
                        style="@android:style/Widget.Button.Small"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="天雨關係 地面濕滑" />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/NoAnimals"
                        style="@android:style/Widget.Button.Small"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="動物及禽鳥" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/Test_FireAlarm_1"
                        style="@android:style/Widget.Button.Small"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="即將 火警系統" />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/Test_FireAlarm_2"
                        style="@android:style/Widget.Button.Small"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="現正 火警系統" />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/Test_Machines"
                        style="@android:style/Widget.Button.Small"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="即將 電力系統" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                </LinearLayout>

            </LinearLayout>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView3"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="九廣西鐵廣播"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/QueuingBox"
                        style="@android:style/Widget.Button.Small"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="排隊標誌" />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/WR_Slippers"
                        style="@android:style/Widget.Button.Small"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="拖鞋涼鞋" />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/NoEat"
                        style="@android:style/Widget.Button.Small"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="安全舒適環境" />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/CuCoctopus"
                        style="@android:style/Widget.Button.Small"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="CuC八達通" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/SitOnFloor"
                        style="@android:style/Widget.Button.Small"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="坐在大堂" />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/StayClear"
                        style="@android:style/Widget.Button.Small"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="大堂入口" />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/Staircase"
                        style="@android:style/Widget.Button.Small"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="上落樓梯 勿奔跑" />

                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/WR_NoSmake"
                        style="@android:style/Widget.Button.Small"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="車站嚴禁吸煙" />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/WR_PickPocket"
                        style="@android:style/Widget.Button.Small"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="扒手 免招損失" />

                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/WR_SvcEnd"
                        style="@android:style/Widget.Button.Small"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="車站關閉" />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/WR_WetFloor"
                        style="@android:style/Widget.Button.Small"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="上落車 地面濕滑" />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/WR_Esclator"
                        style="@android:style/Widget.Button.Small"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="電梯 小童長者" />
                </LinearLayout>

            </LinearLayout>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView4"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="扶手電梯自動廣播"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/Handrail_ER"
                    style="@android:style/Widget.Button.Small"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="ER請緊握扶手" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/Handrail_WR"
                    style="@android:style/Widget.Button.Small"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="WR請緊握扶手" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/Handrail_AUS"
                    style="@android:style/Widget.Button.Small"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="AUS請緊握扶手" />
            </LinearLayout>


        </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/MediaPlayer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="false"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/Stop1"
                style="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.Button.Small"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="◼" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/Play1"
                style="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.Button.Small"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="▶" />

            <SeekBar
                android:id="@+id/Seekbar1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <RadioGroup
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:checkedButton="@+id/Nonetritone"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="廣播提示聲" />

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/Nonetritone"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="-無-" />

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/MTRtritone"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="港鐵" />

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/KCRtritone"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="九鐵" />

            </RadioGroup>

        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Edit 3:
MediaPlayer Layout overlap the ScrollView

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZUmz1.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="to.epac.factorycraft.drawerlayouttest.KCRstationActivity">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="40dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="九廣東鐵廣播"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/AdultTickets"
                        style="@android:style/Widget.Button.Small"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="成人車票" />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/BczOfTheRain"
                        style="@android:style/Widget.Button.Small"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="天雨關係" />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/CrossTrack"
                        style="@android:style/Widget.Button.Small"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="橫過路軌" />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/LifeAnimals"
                        style="@android:style/Widget.Button.Small"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="本公司" />

                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/ER_NoSmoke"
                        style="@android:style/Widget.Button.Small"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="請勿吸煙" />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/ER_PickPocket"
                        style="@android:style/Widget.Button.Small"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="提防扒手" />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/ER_Slippers"
                        style="@android:style/Widget.Button.Small"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="拖鞋涼鞋" />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/ER_SvcEnd"
                        style="@android:style/Widget.Button.Small"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="車站關閉" />

                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/ER_WetFloor_1"
                        style="@android:style/Widget.Button.Small"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="小心濕滑地面" />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/ER_WetFloor_2"
                        style="@android:style/Widget.Button.Small"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="上落車濕滑地面" />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/Esclator"
                        style="@android:style/Widget.Button.Small"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="當使用電梯時" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/Esclator_2"
                        style="@android:style/Widget.Button.Small"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="上落樓梯緊扶手" />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/Luggage_1"
                        style="@android:style/Widget.Button.Small"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="大型行李 升降機" />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/TakeCareChild"
                        style="@android:style/Widget.Button.Small"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="照顧同行小童" />

                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/Luggage_2"
                        style="@android:style/Widget.Button.Small"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="笨重行李 升降機" />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/MetallicBalloon"
                        style="@android:style/Widget.Button.Small"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="金屬氣球" />

                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/WetFloor"
                        style="@android:style/Widget.Button.Small"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="天雨關係 地面濕滑" />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/NoAnimals"
                        style="@android:style/Widget.Button.Small"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="動物及禽鳥" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/Test_FireAlarm_1"
                        style="@android:style/Widget.Button.Small"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="即將 火警系統" />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/Test_FireAlarm_2"
                        style="@android:style/Widget.Button.Small"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="現正 火警系統" />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/Test_Machines"
                        style="@android:style/Widget.Button.Small"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="即將 電力系統" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                </LinearLayout>

            </LinearLayout>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView3"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="九廣西鐵廣播"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/QueuingBox"
                        style="@android:style/Widget.Button.Small"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="排隊標誌" />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/WR_Slippers"
                        style="@android:style/Widget.Button.Small"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="拖鞋涼鞋" />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/NoEat"
                        style="@android:style/Widget.Button.Small"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="安全舒適環境" />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/CuCoctopus"
                        style="@android:style/Widget.Button.Small"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="CuC八達通" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/SitOnFloor"
                        style="@android:style/Widget.Button.Small"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="坐在大堂" />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/StayClear"
                        style="@android:style/Widget.Button.Small"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="大堂入口" />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/Staircase"
                        style="@android:style/Widget.Button.Small"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="上落樓梯 勿奔跑" />

                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/WR_NoSmake"
                        style="@android:style/Widget.Button.Small"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="車站嚴禁吸煙" />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/WR_PickPocket"
                        style="@android:style/Widget.Button.Small"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="扒手 免招損失" />

                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/WR_SvcEnd"
                        style="@android:style/Widget.Button.Small"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="車站關閉" />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/WR_WetFloor"
                        style="@android:style/Widget.Button.Small"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="上落車 地面濕滑" />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/WR_Esclator"
                        style="@android:style/Widget.Button.Small"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="電梯 小童長者" />
                </LinearLayout>

            </LinearLayout>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView4"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="扶手電梯自動廣播"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/Handrail_ER"
                    style="@android:style/Widget.Button.Small"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="ER請緊握扶手" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/Handrail_WR"
                    style="@android:style/Widget.Button.Small"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="WR請緊握扶手" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/Handrail_AUS"
                    style="@android:style/Widget.Button.Small"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="AUS請緊握扶手" />
            </LinearLayout>


        </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/MediaPlayer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/Stop1"
                style="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.Button.Small"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="◼" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/Play1"
                style="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.Button.Small"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="▶" />

            <SeekBar
                android:id="@+id/Seekbar1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <RadioGroup
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:checkedButton="@+id/Nonetritone"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="廣播提示聲" />

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/Nonetritone"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="-無-" />

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/MTRtritone"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="港鐵" />

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/KCRtritone"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="九鐵" />

            </RadioGroup>

        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I can make my MediaPlayer controller at the bottom but I can't put my buttonsssssss (with lots of LinearLayout and textView) inside the ListView :(

Comment: @BrianLiu you need to use custom layout in listview

Comment: if you want to add lots of **textView** than what you want to display in listview @BrianLiu

Comment: Please check out the edited post. I added a picture in order to show what I'm trying to do. (Don't care about those non-english characters I'm from HongKong

Comment: @BrianLiu simple make your layout **android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"**

Comment: Please check the updated post again, I've posted the source code I've done so far, would you like to help me edit this or tell me where and what I have to add stuff? Thanks

Comment: Please Check the updated post, MediaPlayer LinearLayout overlapped ScrollView :(

Comment: The last 2 row (扶手電梯自動廣播, 3 buttons) got covered by **MediaPlayer** 's background color

Comment: there is no other way to do it @BrianLiu

Comment: Oh... If there is no way to achieve this I have to put **MediaPlayer** back on top :(

Comment: It overlaps the top row now instead of the bottom 2 row ... But that's fine I've made the one on top. Just wanted to make that at the bottom. But there is no way I can get this done :/ I will take it.

Comment: Thank you so much for using your time in answering my questions. But I'm still unable to put it bottom so I think I can't click the tick button. I'm sooo sorry :(

Comment: @BrianLiu you  need to set margin to your scrollview check updated ans i'm sure it will solve your issue

Comment: That's awesome! You didn't give me up and you made it <3 btw I changed the Layout_margin bottom from 40dp to 80dp since 40dp is not enough

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using `ListView` and layout at the bottom of the screen and eliminate `scrollView`.